# Remove all files with a common prefix except the N latest modified

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to create a bash command/script to remove all files in a directory older than X days that starts with a certain substring.

For example, if our directory contains the files

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jun 30 10:22 foo_5
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jun 29 10:22 bar_4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jun 29 10:22 foo_4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jun 28 10:22 bar_3
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jun 28 10:22 foo_3
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jun 27 10:22 bar_2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jun 27 10:22 foo_2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jun 26 10:22 foo_1
```

we want to delete all `foo*` files except the 2 most recent one. This will result in the directory

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jun 30 10:22 foo_5
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jun 29 10:22 bar_4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jun 29 10:22 foo_4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jun 28 10:22 bar_3
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jun 27 10:22 bar_2
```

I am currently only able to delete all files except the 2 most recent, which will affect `bar*` files.

```
ls -t | tail -n +4 | xargs rm --
```

How can we also restrict our deletion to files that starts with a certain string?

---

**Code to create test files**

```
(
touch -d "6 days ago" foo_5
touch -d "7 days ago" foo_4
touch -d "7 days ago" bar_4
touch -d "8 days ago" foo_3
touch -d "8 days ago" bar_3
touch -d "9 days ago" foo_2
touch -d "9 days ago" bar_2
touch -d "10 days ago" foo_1
)
```

Comment: Try `ls -t foo*`.

Comment: Why can't you use `find`?  look up the `-mtime` attribute if you are looking for modified or `-atime` only for access

Comment: @Inian : With this approach, you can only find files modified a certain time ago. This is not what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @user1934428: Yes agreed, but was seeking a clarification from them, why using `find` was not was considered

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Parsing the output of `ls` [is not a good idea](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Using tools from GNU coreutils and findutils packages, a fail-safe program to achieve this task can be written as below.

```
n=2 # except the last two
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'foo*' \
     -printf '%T@\t%p\0'              \
| sort  -z -k 1n,1                    \
| head  -z -n -$n                     \
| cut   -z -f 2-                      \
| xargs -0 rm
```

Comment: Excellent! Using `\0` and `-z` is the safest way to go

Answer (score 1):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) and `glob()` (handle files with newlines or spaces as well) via only *one process*:

```
perl -e '
    my @files = sort { -M $a <=> -M $b } grep -f, <./foo*>;
    unlink @files[2..$#files]
'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for `stat`

```sh
stat -c '%Y %n' foo* | sort -n | head -n -2 | cut -d " " -f 2- | xargs echo rm
```

```
rm foo_1 foo_2 foo_3
```

Remove "echo" if it is selecting the right files to delete.